# What are the ways by which a demigod can be elevated to a god?

Tags: percy-jackson, greek-myth

At the end of *The Last Olympian*, we see that Zeus offers godhood to Percy Jackson, and he rejects it, in favour of another wish. Can a demigod achieve godhood by other means? For instance, could Percy have become a god, by living in Poseidon's domain entirely, practicing his powers over the domain and becoming one with it?

Comment: Not sure why this is DV'd.  Seems like he's asking for known methods that might apply within the Percy Jackson series' continuity to me.  Asking about general Greek Mythology I can see being too broad, but this does pertain to a specific work of fiction.

Answer (score 2):

In *Percy Jackson's Greek Gods*, it is mentioned that Dionysus was a half-blood but due to his creation of wine he got many followers who worshipped him like a god, so he turned into a real god (in Greek mythology the more worshippers the gods get the stronger they become).

Also in the same book, the gods Demeter, Zeus, and Athena cast spells to turn a demigod into a god, which were obstructed by someone, but if they were successfully performed the targets would have transformed into gods.

Comment: Can you possibly provide a quote, or some evidence to support your answer?

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Dionysus was made into a God by Zeus. In PJO Dionysus says that he was conferred Godhood by Zeus for inventing wine. But I believe the question is asking about becoming a God through a person's own efforts, without godhood being conferred by other gods.

Answer (score 2):

Legacies can become gods (well, god-emperors) if they are worshipped by their followers. Nero is one example:

> Will stepped back. “You’re saying the emperors of ancient Rome are alive? *How?* The Doors of Death?"
>
> "No." I could barely speak through the taste of bile. "**The emperors made themselves gods. They had their own temples and altars. They encouraged the people to worship them.**"
>
> "But that was just propaganda," Nico said. "They weren't really divine."
>
> I laughed mirthlessly. "**Gods are sustained by worship**, son of Hades. **They continue to exist because of the collective memories of a culture**. It's true for the Olympians; it's also true for the emperors. Somehow, the most powerful of them have survived. All these centuries, they have clung to half-life, hiding, waiting to
> reclaim their power."
>
> *(The Trials of Apollo: The Hidden Oracle - Chapter 27)*

> “Lord Apollo, please,” he said. “Even before Gaea commandeered the Doors of Death, souls escaped from Erebos all the time. It was quite easy for a god-emperor such as myself to call back my followers.”
>
> “A god-emperor?” I growled. “You mean a delusional ex-emperor.”
>
> Nero arched his eyebrows. “What made you a god, Apollo...back when you were one? Wasn’t it **the power of your name, your sway over those who believed in you**? I am no different.” He glanced to his left. “Vince, fall on your spear, please.”
>
> Without hesitation, Vince planted the butt of his spear against the ground. He braced the point under his rib cage.
>
> “Stop,” Nero said. “I changed my mind.”
>
> Vince betrayed no relief. In fact, his eyes tightened with faint disappointment. He brought his spear back to his side.
>
> Nero grinned at me. “You see? I hold the **power of life and death over my worshippers**, like any proper god should.”
>
> I felt like I’d swallowed some gel capsule larvae. “The Germani were always crazy, much like you.”
>
> Nero put his hand to his chest. “I’m hurt! My barbarian friends are loyal subjects of the Julian dynasty! And, of course, **we are all descended from you, Lord Apollo.**”
>
> *(The Trials of Apollo: The Hidden Oracle - Chapter 29)*

If legacies can become gods through this route, I'm fairly certain that demigods can also do so.

Answer (score 1):

A demigod can become a god by drinking from the Chalice of the Gods as shown in Percy Jackson and the Chalice of the Gods.

Comment: According to the description on Riordan's site, the Chalice grants immortality, not godhead.  Can you quote a passage from the book that demonstrates this?